# Is there any easy way to solve two equations with three unknowns?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

Is there a way to solve the below simultaneous equations?

One possible solution is $a_1=20.0948$, $a_2=10.0948$, $a_3=6.3448$.
The variables are actually dual variables of the binding constraints.
The system of equations is actually encompassing the relationship between the dual variables.

$$a_1-a_2=10$$

$$a_3-a_2=3.75$$

One can also derive that:

$$a_1-a_3=6.25$$

Comment: You have two equations and three unknowns. Does that sound solvable to you?

Comment: yes, by keeping one variable constant :)

Comment: I posted one of the solution to this equation. One can recognize a pattern in the solution. I wonder about the pattern in the solution.

Comment: You can think of a linear equation with three variables as a plane. If you solve two equations simultaneously, you are finding the intersection of two planes, which is (usually) a line. So you will have a 1D set of solutions, not just 1,

Comment: A set of solutions is true; but some how the dual variables are related with each other according to a  implicit scaling factor.

Comment: The simplest way is [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Elementary_example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This system has infinitely many solutions of the form $a_2=t$, $a_1=t+10$ and $a_3=t+3.75$. The solution set is in fact a line in $\mathbb R^3$ given by $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(10,0,3.75)+t(1,1,1)$.

Comment: What do u mean with t(1,1,1)?

Comment: It's vector notation. It means that the solution is a line that you get by starting in $(10,0,3.75)$ an continuing in the direction $(1,1,1)$

Comment: You can give any value to $t$ and get a solution. For example: t=2, (10,0,3.75)+(2,2,2)=(12,2,5.75).

Comment: it means than a vector like (t,t,t) where t is constant?

Comment: I see, thx for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is classically solved by looking at the *augmented matrix* associated to your system
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -1 & 0 & 10 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & \frac{15}{4}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Using [elementary row operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) allows us to write our system in [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). In our case we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -1 & 0 & 10 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & \frac{15}{4}
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & -1 & \frac{25}{4} \\
0 & 1 & -1 & -\frac{15}{4}
\end{array}\right]
$$
This allows us to read off the solutions "cleanly". The reduced matrix  corresponds to the equation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\ a_2\\ a_3
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
25/4+a_3\\ -15/4+a_3\\a_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
25/4\\ -15/4\\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
+
a_3
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 1\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
That is, plugging *any* choice of $a_3$ into (1) gives a solution. Thus the original system has infinitely many solutions.